# Replace string in all files if surroundings match expectations

Tags: regex, shell

I have 3rd party software (A PHP application in this case) that creates and sets file acces rights all over the code. For dev reasons I want them all set to 0777.

What I got:

```
grep --include \*.php -rnP '[,=>]{1,2}\s*(0[67][0-6]{2})\s*[,;)]' * 2>/dev/null
```

will return something like

```
engine/Library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php:104:           'hashed_directory_perm' => 0700,
engine/Library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php:106:        'cache_file_perm' => 0600,
recovery/common/vendor/knplabs/gaufrette/src/Gaufrette/Stream/Local.php:36:            @mkdir($baseDirPath, 0755, true);
vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/ProxyGenerator.php:305:        chmod($tmpFileName, 0664);
    vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/EntityRepositoryGenerator.php:155:            chmod($path, 0664);
vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Export/Driver/AbstractExporter.php:148:                chmod($path, 0664);
vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/EntityGenerator.php:392:        chmod($path, 0664);
vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Cache/Region/FileLockRegion.php:245:        chmod($filename, 0664);
vendor/league/flysystem/src/Adapter/Local.php:33:            'public' => 0744,
vendor/league/flysystem/src/Adapter/Local.php:34:            'private' => 0700,
```

Now at this point I found all the files and places I need to adapt, but have no Idea how to actually replace the numbers.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-l` option in `grep` and pipe it to `xargs` with a `sed`:

```
grep --include \*.php -rlP '[,=>]{1,2}\s*(0[67][0-6]{2})\s*[,;)]' * 2>/dev/null |
xargs -I {} sed -i.bak 's/0[67][0-6][0-6]/0777/g' {}
```

Comment: Since I used `grep -l` so all we should be getting from `grep` is just the filenames